# Firefox portable deactivates several addons when using USB-Stick on another PC

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, portable

My USB stick with Firefox portable works fine on my laptop, but if I use it in any desktop PC, Firefox addons manager deactivates several (not all, but always the same) addons, so I have to update all and activate.

Do some addons save necessary temporary files to the PC even though this is a portable version of Firefox, and is not installed on the local machine?

**Are there any other download sources for Firefox portable builds i can test than on portableapps.com?**

Comment: If you re-insert the usb stick with portable ff back into the same desktop after re-activating the extensions, do they remain re-activated?

Comment: @Paul yes, thats the case. Only if I switch between two different OS, **several addons** (but quite much, 20 out of 25 get deactivated), also with another USB stick. I deactivated already automatic updating in firefox settings, but doesnt help.